# Vim Highlight only the characters, which produce comments

Tags: vim

I am trying to achieve the following. If I have a file, e.g. a tex document and I want to have the following with commenting characters (% symbols) highlighted:

```
%
Some text and end of the sentence.
%
Some more text.
```

I already know how to highlight commented lines, but that is not exactly what I want.

Also, I can achieve the desired effect if I just search for the % symbol, but I am too lazy to do that every time after I search anything else.

I also would like to have a config so that in other languages I would have the same (e.g. -- symbols for lua, or # symbol for bash)

Does anybody know how to do that elegantly in my .vimrc file?

Comment: EDIT1: I just wanted to add, that I would like to know whether it is possible to abstract things in vim. I wanted to have a simple solution where I search for a comment char, and not for the percent sign. Something like /${CommentChar} and not just /%


Somehow I start to think that I want too much and the easiest way to do this is just using a macro Sudipta Chatterjee suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Vim macro.

In the command mode, use press `q` to enable macro mode, and let's call your search highlight a macro 's' - meaning go ahead and press 's'. Now you can search for all the '%' characters by first setting `:set hlsearch` (just to make sure) and then entering `/%`. Then, you can save this macro by pressing `q` again. After this, whenever you enter `@s` in the command mode you will get your search characters highlighted.

You can save the above macro into your `.vimrc` file by adding this:

```
let @s='/%'
```

You can also enable the search character as a macro argument for different file types.